# Connecting to mysql from docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a node app I want to run on docker. The app works on my localhost but when I build it on docke, I keep getting a connection error specifying my database connection fails.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:27:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

here's my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqlcontain
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./mydatabase.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_mydatabase.sql
      - $HOME/doh_database:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ctf
      MYSQL_USER: psychval
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbsecret
      SERVICE_TAGS: prod
      SERVICE_NAME: mysqldb
    networks:
      - bridge

  nodeapp:
    container_name: nodeappcontainer
    build: .
    image: cystartr:v1
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    expose:
      - 5000
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb    

    environment:
      DATABASE: ctf
      DATABASE_HOST: mysqldb
      DATABASE_USER: psychval
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: "dbsecret"
      SERVICE_TAGS: prod
      SERVICE_NAME: nodeappservice
    networks:
      - bridge

networks:
  bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

and here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/3306; do sleep 1; done; node app.js> node app.js']
```

It's my first time working with docker and I haven't fully grasped the concept, so i had checked some solutions proposed on stackoverflow. it's why i changed the block of code
`CMD [bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/3306; do sleep 1; done; node app.js> node app.js']` 
from : `CMD "node", "app.js"`. This was because I saw it was a possibility the app starts before the database connection is established